# Will ATT affects general firebase and google analytics other than the ad tracking?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, apptrackingtransparency

I am using latest firebase sdk in my iOS app. I want to add ATT(AppTrackingTransparency) alert in my app. If user selected "Do not track" option from alert, will it affect the firebase and google analytics too other than the ad analytics? From basic google analytics I meant for example which screen user visited, which button user clicked, total time spent by user on a screen etc.

Please guide.

Comment: I am actually having the same question. I'm using Google Analytics from firebase only on the app. SetCurrentScreen(title, viewName); 

I'm not sure if we need to provide an alert at all if we are only doing that.

Comment: did you manage to find this ?